# How to format inital date value using AngularJS ui-date directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

When I get a model from the server it looks like this:

```
$scope.m = 
{
   name: "John",
   Dt:   "2013-10-03T18:47:33.5049087-07:00"
};
```

The view looks like:

```
<input title="Date" ui-date ng-model="m.Dt" />
```

I set the default date format on the jQuery datepicker to:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
```

The initial value of the input stays "2013-10-03T18:47:33.5049087-07:00" though. It only formats as `mm-dd-yy` if I use the datepicker to change the date.

How can I get the initial value to also be in `mm-dd-yy` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $scope.m.Dt property should be of **date type**, not string.

```
$scope.m = 
{
   name: "John",
   Dt:   new Date()
};
```

To set date format use **ui-date-format** directive, like:

```
<input title="Date" ui-date ui-date-format="mm-dd-yy" ng-model="m.Dt" />
```

See example in readme: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date#ui-date-format-directive

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it works with Date objects, but in a real world example your data comes from the server likely via JSON and your dates will not be objects, but strings. I can write a method to recurse thru the model and convert date strings to objects, but I was thinking for such a common scenario it would already be handled.

Comment: It's not handled in angular, but you can create http interceptor with recursive method to convert date strings to objects as you mentioned. See this post for example: http://aboutcode.net/2013/07/27/json-date-parsing-angularjs.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "date" is just a string, Angular wants a native Date object (or a timestamp).

I've found two ways of dealing with this: Scrub the data right away or watch the variable and reassign its type.

My preferred solution is to munge the data when it's brought in. Since I know the object has a `date`, I just scrub the JSON data from the `$http` `success` promise like this:

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
    data.date = Date.parse(data.date);
    $scope.model = data;
}
```

That converts the data before it's assigned to `$scope`, so Angular will see `$scope.model.date` as a native JS Date object format it correctly.

The other solution is to specifically `$watch` the variable's type. Somewhere in the controller, add this:

```
$scope.$watch('model.date', function() {
    if (typeof $scope.model.date === 'string') {
        $scope.model.date = Date.parse($scope.model.date);
    }
});
```

That checks the type everytime `$scope.model.date` is modified. Obviously, that's more overhead, but might be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is what I did using Jquery-UI calendar with Angularjs

> date format was "2015-03-24T04:00:00"

First trim the date string to get only year, month, and date.

```
var date = "2015-03-24T04:00:00"
var formattedDate = date.match(/[\d-]+/).pop();
// formattedDate is now "2015-03-24" which is passed into
// the directive below as the input.$modelValue.
```

Now, inside your directive or controller do the following...

```
// Here is directive example.
link: function( scope, element, attrs, input ){

  element.datepicker( optionsObjectHere );
  setInitialDateFormatOnInput();

  function setInitialDateFormatOnInput(){
    setTimeout(function(){ // This timeout is required to delay the directive for the input.modelValue to resolve, however, no actual delay occurs!
      element.datepicker( "setDate", formatToJqueryUIDateFormat());
    });
  }

  function formatToJqueryUIDateFormat(){
    return $.datepicker.parseDate( 'yy-mm-dd', input.$modelValue );
    // 'yy-mm-dd' needs to match the input.$modelValue format from above. 
  }
} // link
```

This is how I use the entire jquery UI on my inputs.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="inline" ng-model="inputValue" my-calendar-popup="calendarOptions" />
```

> Where calendarOptions is the following object

```
  var calendarOptions = { minDate: 0, buttonImage: "calendar-icon.png", buttonImageOnly: 'true', showOn: "both", dateFormat: "MM d, yy" };
```

DIRECTIVE

```
app.directive('myCalendarPopup', function(){

  var defaultOptions = { minDate: 0, buttonImage: "calendar-icon.png",   buttonImageOnly: 'true', showOn: "both", dateFormat: "MM d, yy" };
  // defaultOptions just in case someone doesn't pass in options.

  return {
    require:'?ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function( scope, element, attrs, input ){
      if ( !input ){ return; } // If no ngModel then return;

      element.datepicker( createCalendarOptions());
      setInitialDateFormatOnInput();

      function createCalendarOptions(){
        if( !attrs.rsCalendarPopup ){ return addRequiredJqueryFunction( defaultOptions );}
        return formatOptions();
      }

      function formatOptions() {
        var options = scope.$eval( attrs.rsCalendarPopup );
        // Turn string into object above.
        return addRequiredJqueryFunction( options );
      }

      function addRequiredJqueryFunction( options ){
        options.onSelect = changeDate;
        // add onSelect to passed in object and reference local changeDate function, which will update changes to input.$modelValue.
        return options;
      }

      function changeDate( date ){
        input.$setViewValue( date );
      }

      function setInitialDateFormatOnInput(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        // This timeout is required to delay the directive for the input.modelValue to resolve.
        // However, there is no actual timeout time. This is a must to get
        // Angular to behave.
          element.datepicker( "setDate", formatToJqueryUIDateFormat());
        });
      }

      function formatToJqueryUIDateFormat(){
        return $.datepicker.parseDate( 'yy-mm-dd', input.$modelValue );
        // 'yy-mm-dd' is not the format you want the calendar to be
        // it is the format the original date shows up as.
        // you set your actual formatting using the calendar options at
        // the top of this directive or inside the passed in options.
        // The key is called dateFormat, in this case it's set as
        // dateFormat: "MM d, yy" which makes June 30, 2015.
      }
    } // link
  } // return
});
```

> Note: I can only get this to work in it's displayed configuration. I have added it to a controller, and even a directive controller and could not recreate the initial date condition. I have not found out why this is yet. Perhaps this solution works only within a link function that is embedded in another isolated scope directive and works due to specific timing.